# How to programmatically mute live streaming video in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, volume, avplayer

I am playing live streaming video in iPhone using AVPlayer. I want to switch off the volume of the player (programmatically). I tried this http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1716/_index.html. But it is not working in my case.

```
AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:[self myAssetURL] options:nil];
NSArray *audioTracks = [asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];

// Mute all the audio tracks
NSMutableArray *allAudioParams = [NSMutableArray array];
for (AVAssetTrack *track in audioTracks) {
    AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *audioInputParams =[AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParameters];
    [audioInputParams setVolume:0.0 atTime:kCMTimeZero];
    [audioInputParams setTrackID:[track trackID]];
    [allAudioParams addObject:audioInputParams];
}
AVMutableAudioMix *audioZeroMix = [AVMutableAudioMix audioMix];
[audioZeroMix setInputParameters:allAudioParams];

// Create a player item
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
[playerItem setAudioMix:audioZeroMix]; // Mute the player item

// Create a new Player, and set the player to use the player item 
// with the muted audio mix
AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];

// assign player object to an instance variable
self.mPlayer = player;

// play the muted audio
[mPlayer play];
```

Please suggest any solution for this.
Thanks

Comment: What have you done so far? Show us some code

Comment: I think you are out of luck. Please [see this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12046195/312312)

Comment: I believe there is no option to mute the video in live streaming. So far I know. you can make use of the Volume control in MPMoviePlayerController to do this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **MPVolumeView** class, available [here]. It has a slider for volume control, that works for HTTP Live Streams as well.(http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPVolumeView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)